# A good .NET code formatter

Tags: .net, asp.net, code-formatting

could you point me a good .NET Code formatter?

I would like to post pieces of code in my website and make them look beautiful.

The formatter it self would be great if it had extra option(s) like code selection by copying to clipboard.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify, code formatting sometimes means wrapping long lines, correcting indentation etc.  Do you mean formatting as in colours, fonts etc?  If so what output format - HTML, PDF, bitmap image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

or http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Both will solve your problem. Here is an example using prettify http://docs.bendsoft.com/camelot-net-connector/1_1/programming/connecting-to-sharepoint/opening-the-connection/

Answer (score 0):

Most versatile code formatter/highligher I know is [highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/).

You should take a look at [Smashing Magazine's Code Beautifier / Code Highlighter post](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/12/time-savers-code-beautifier-and-formatter/). It contains more code highlighters than you can shake your stick at.